# Use a JavaScript Symbol as an input/checkbox label identifier

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility

I'm in the process of writing a component wrapping an HTML checkbox element to easily manage the label and make it accessible. I've just learned about [JavaScript Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) and wanted to know if there was any harm in using them as a unique identifier in the `for` attribute of a `label`. Here is the code of such a component using React:

```js
const Checkbox = ({ label }) => {
 const id = Symbol().toString();

 return (
   <div>
     <input type="checkbox" id={id} />
     <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
   </div>
 );
};
```

[image: Edit poc-label-for-and-js-symbol]

Comment: What? `Symbol().toString();` doesn't give you unique strings (`'Symbol()'`) which is what for expects if your component is reusable. What do you think you're doing here? Symbols are not serializable and can't be used as unique identifiers for ids.

Comment: Have you checked the value of `id`? If so, why do you expect that string to be unique?

Comment: Also, I don't believe `Symbol.toString()` would output characters that are valid IDs...

Comment: @HereticMonkey The only invalid character is a space? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/html-valid-id-attribute-values. You mean if they used `Symbol('a b').toString();`?

Comment: Yes I misunderstand the fact that `Symbol().toString() === Symbol().toString()` is `true` 

Comment: @RuanMendes Those answers are no longer true for today's DOM. anything will now be considered valid when naming attributes in html (including spaces `.querySelector('#app header')` 

Comment: @RuanMendes When I run `Symbol().toString()` I get `"Symbol()"`. AFAIK, parentheses are not valid in IDs.

Comment: @TachibanaShin You misunderstood something. What you posted is a selector. The answer I linked to says that in HTML5, an **id** can have any characters, the only restriction is that it cannot contains spaces. In your example, the id is `app` and it does not contain spaces.

Comment: @RuanMendes I can name the id of the tags containing spaces (and I usually do it like this `<div id='app header'>`

Comment: @HereticMonkey The answer I linked to says otherwise. `HTML 5 is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at least one character and may not contain any space characters.`

Comment: @RuanMendes I don't know if HTML5 hates it or not, but the DOM API still allow me to query them legally.

Comment: @TachibanaShin That will look for a `header` element that is a descendant of an element with the ID "app". If an ID has special symbols, they must be escaped in the selector.

Comment: @RuanMendes My only defense: I'm old ;-)

Comment: @TachibanaShin  @Heretic Monkey I stand corrected, you can escape the space and it works and the current spec does not list any limitation on characters. `There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.`.  The following works fine`document.querySelector('#my\\ id .class\\(\\)')` to find an element with class `class()`within id `my id`. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: Yeah, I think you misunderstood the point of `Symbol` here, in a way you can think of them like an empty object `{}`, so `{} === {}  -> false`, both those `{}` are unique.   But the issue with `{}` is that it can't be used as a property name, but a `Symbol` can, and that's very useful, eg. `{ [Symbol.iterator]: () => { ...... }}` is an object that has the ability to iterate..  That `Symbol.iterator` is guaranteed, eg. if you did -> `[Symbol('Symbol.iterator')]:`  that would be something totally different, and pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`symbol` is one of the new data types since ES6 that only represents a unique characteristic while it is still itself

When you `.toString()`, the symbols will immediately be forced into a normal string state and will no longer be unique. (`Symbol().toString()` always result `"Symbol()"`):

Use unique number:

```
let index = 1;
const Checkbox = ({ label }) => {
 const id = '_' + (index++).toString(36)

 return (
   <div>
     <input type="checkbox" id={id} />
     <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
   </div>
 );
};
```

Comment: @RuanMendes removed!

Comment: Woaw that's right `Symbol().toString() === Symbol().toString()` is true... I thought wrong. Thanks for the answer ;)